# Advice on writing generic function to encode variables in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame:

```
mydata = data.frame(v1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D"),
                v2 = c("XY", "XY", "ZZ", "BB", "ZZ", NA, "ZZ"),
                v3 = 5)
```

And I would like to encode each of the characters in the data frame to integers corresponding to each of the levels.  I also want to "ignore" NA values.  The expected output would be equal to:

```
output = data.frame(v1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4),
                 v2 = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 2, NA, 2),
                 v3 = 5)
```

My hope is to write a function that accepts a data.frame object AND a list specifying the columns on which I want to perform the operation, something like:

```
my_function = function(df, vars){
  ...
}
```

EDIT:  in the example above, "vars" would be = c("v1", "v2")

Any suggestions for how to approach this?  I'm open to using packages such as dplyr to help.

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert to `factor` and then coerce to `numeric`

```
mydata[1:2] <- lapply(mydata[1:2], function(x) 
     as.numeric(factor(x, levels=unique(x))))
```

This can be converted to a function

```
myfunction <- function(df, vars) {
   df[vars] <- lapply(df[vars], function(x) 
             as.numeric(factor(x, levels=unique(x))))
   df
 }

myfunction(mydata, c('v1', 'v2'))

#  v1 v2 v3
#1  1  1  5
#2  1  1  5
#3  1  2  5
#4  2  3  5
#5  2  2  5
#6  3 NA  5
#7  4  2  5
```

If we need it to be further generalized, we may need to check the column classes i.e.  whether it is a `numeric` column and if not, then change to `factor` with `levels` specified and coerce to `numeric`.

```
 mydata[] <- lapply(mydata, function(x) 
        if(!is.numeric(x)) as.numeric(factor(x, levels=unique(x))) 
             else x)
```